# Frequency modulator won't oscillate

Tags: rf, oscillator, radio, modulation

I'm student and I'm working on a school project. The project is a radio transmitter.

My question here is only about the frequency modulator part.

Here is my circuit :

[image]

Here is my output signal (blue) and input signal (brown) :

[image]

As you can see there is no modulation what so ever.

According to my teacher, my output should look something like this if my oscillating frequency is 93 MHz and my input signal is at 9.3 MHz:

[image]

My oscillating frequency is supposed to be 93 MHz. Here is how I did my calculations:

[image]

The *1.3 is just to make sure I respect the Barkhausen criterion

Do you guys have any suggestions to get an output at 93MHz when I input a signal at 9.3MHz?

Edit : I know the oscillating frequency can be calculated with the formula above but how can one theoretically calculate the amplitude of the oscillation and what affects it? I'm guessing RC and RL. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove CC3. Does it oscillate now? If so you must find a way to supply the input (modulating) signal without presenting the low impedance to GND that CC3 and the AC source does.

Comment: Exactly my thought @BrianDrummond - it's not that there's no modulation - there's no oscillation. So remove 9open circuit) CC3 and get your circuit to oscillate. Then replace CC3 but have the modulation signal replaced by a short circuit and I bet it doesn't oscillate.

Comment: @Andyak & BrianDrummond thanks for the answers!! However if I open circuit (remove) CC3 then I just have nothing in simulation... Is it normal in simulation ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Then  the oscillator isn't starting. What does the transient response look like if you connect R1 to a 9V step instead of +9V DC? That might be enough to kick the oscillator into life. (CC3 still open cct)

Comment: The 2N2222 is a tad shabby for 93 MHz - it has an fT of only 250 MHz and you are trying to make a 93 MHz oscillator - try an inductor with 100 times the value to see if it starts oscillating. Also try Re at ten times lower and ditch the Ce capacitor.

Comment: @BrianDrummond So the "there's no oscillation" is now fixed! A step of +9V DC did the trick! thanks. I try connecting the source now! I'll also try your suggestion AndyAka! thx guys

Comment: You may find the source kills the oscillation again. If so, you may need to connect it via a fairly large R (up to a similar value to RB1,2) and adjust input amplitude to suit.

Comment: might want to replace 9V with a stepped 9V source to create a transient output that can kick start oscillations. It could also be that the gain for amplifier isn’t enough. Simulation with oscillators can be a bit tricky sometimes.

Comment: I swear you guys are making it work and it all makes sense now!! So I added back CC3, added an R of 400k (ish) between CC3 and the source and everything works well! I have my modulation. I have however a small problem. My Vout has a DC component even tho I have a capacitor just before... isnt it weird?

Comment: That dc component might be from the transient response. If you look at waveform after a certain amount of time, it should settle to zero.

Comment: Please do update your question with the final circuit and don't worry about the DC on the output - it will settle. Or make an answer yourself with the final circuit (better resolution if you can please).

Comment: I'll do that !!!! Thx guys!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks to @BrianDrummond, @Andyak and @Leoman12 !!

This is my circuit now :

[image]

This is my transient :

[image]

As you can see it now oscillates. Theres is a DC component on the Vout but it goes away with time. Its hard to simulate because it would take a while with Orcad (my software) and a high resolution (low max step size).

So the key points were to :

- Change the DC source to Step
- Add RB3